# Vue 2.6.10 - How to fix 'Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.' in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've created a data table that will take data from an API and display it nicely. I want the user to be able to double click on any row and have a modal component pop up that displays the information of that row.

The data is an array of objects:

```
[
    { text: 'some data 1', value: 'some info 1' },
    { text: 'some data 2', value: 'some info 2' },
    { text: 'some data 3', value: 'some info 3' },
    { text: 'some data 4', value: 'some info 4' },
]
```

I've tried binding the object to the component directly, making the parts of the table their own components, using `$emit`, and now using the original value from the for loop and an index but nothing has worked for me.

This is what I use to create the table after I make the headers:

```
<tr class="notheader" v-for="(sortedobject,index) in sortedvalues"
    v-on:dblclick="$emit('open', sortedobject); showModal = true;">
    <!-- Many <td></td> -->
    <modal v-bind:modaldata="sortedvalues[index]" v-on:close="showModal = false" v-if="showModal">
        <h1 slot="header">Nonsense header</h1>
    </modal>
</tr>
```

This is my component:

```
var Child = {
    template: '#modal-template',
    props: ['modaldata'],
    mounted: function () {
        this.$parent.$on('update', this.setValue);
    }
};
```

The template is just a wireframe of what it should look like.

I expect `modaldata` to contain all the data from the object for that row, but I get undefined and the error I am currently getting is:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: Not enough information. Based on the error message, there should be a place where you wrote `this.index`.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `:modaldata="sortedobject"`. Do you get the same error message if you do that? Also, what component is triggering the error? What does your `#modal-template` look like?

Comment: Phil - My template looks like this [link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/wOke9B7d) and the error message is the same as before if I changed `v-bind:modaldata="sortedvalues[index]"` to `:modaldata="sortedobject"` except "index" has been replaced with "sortedobject"

Yong Quan - I've searched through my entire project and `this.index` is never written anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my own issue:

I solved this by making a method on `v-on:dblclick="showModal = true; getModalData(index)"`
The method sets a variable named `curentModalData` in the parent `data` section to `sortedvalues[index]` which the modal can bind to:

`<modal v-bind:modaldata="curentModalData" ...>`